# CAN-BUS in a SEAT cordoba 99'

Tags: obd-ii

Does anyone know if SEAT cordoba (99' model) has CAN-BUS interface? 
Where can one find this kind of info?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Judging by this...

> CAN bus is one of five protocols used in the OBD-II vehicle
> diagnostics standard. The OBD-II standard has been mandatory for all
> cars and light trucks sold in the United States since 1996, and the
> EOBD standard has been mandatory for all petrol vehicles sold in the
> European Union since 2001 and all diesel vehicles since 2004.

Source: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAN_bus)
I venture to say no, as all mentions of CAN bus I found were post 2001 for Cordovas made by SEAT.